App Store Connect does not allow to create new app version asking for License Agreement Update
I am trying to add new app version and get the following alert:
Agreement Update
The Apple Developer Program License Agreement has been updated and needs to be reviewed. In order to update your existing apps and submit new apps, the Account Holder must review and accept the updated agreement by signing in to their account on the Apple Developer website.

But developer portal does not contain any pending agreements.
Apple Developer Program License Agreement
Issued June 10, 2024. Accepted June 27, 2024.

Apple Developer Agreement
Issued June 8, 2015. Accepted August 29, 2018.

I had similar issue before, and after clicking Add Version multiple times, it eventually allowed to create new release, but now that does not work.

Although alert, presented from "Add Version" button, was mentioning Apple Developer Program License Agreement to be accepted, after navigating around other App Store Connect pages, I found the following banner:

Review the updated Paid Applications Schedule.
In order to update your
existing apps, create new in-app purchases, and submit new apps to the
App Store, the user with the Legal role (Account Holder) must review
and accept the Paid Applications Schedule (Schedule 2 to the Apple
Developer Program License Agreement) in the Agreements, Tax, and
Banking module.

After accepting Paid Applications Schedule terms, the problem was solved.
